# Android - what's the permission difference on normal and rooted devices

Tags: root, android

I have two android phones, one rooted the other not. When I run following code without asking for root permission on the two phones,

```c
system("echo \"abc\" > /data/a.txt\n");
```

the rooted phone returns me error-2 (512); the normal phone returns error-1 (256, permission denied). So my question is, what makes this difference.

Comment: BTW: We do have an Android site, but since you asked here, I'm assuming you want to look at this from the Linux level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on my desktop Linux system, errno 2 is `ENOENT`, i.e., no such file or directory. You can find out with the `errno` command (though you probably don't have that on the phone).

That could mean you don't have a /data on that phone (which would be odd). My rooted phone (Galaxy Nexus, running stock Jelly Jean 4.2.2) gives permission denied when I try that in a shell (not in a C program, as you appear to be doing)

I suggest `ls -ld /data` to start, and maybe also `which echo` to see if something is different there. Or possibly you don't have a shell; does `system("true")` work?

Comment: Thank you Derobert. Both phones have /data for sure. So ideally, being a normal user, when executing the same commands on both phones, there should be no difference, is this correct? Even if one phone is rooted.

Comment: Rooting alone shouldn't make a difference there. (Rooting just installs `su` and superuser.apk/supersu.apk/etc.)